# Find users by number of questions / number of answers

Tags: support, data-explorer

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to get a list of users with more/less than X questions and/or with more/less than Y answers?

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by user @rene on chat, here is a query helpful for this purpose:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/594383?q=500&a=100

(Older version: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/594367/users-with-specific-numbers-of-questions-answers?q=500&a=100)